# Set up fsf gdb on Mac OS 10.9

Tags: macos, qt, gdb, installation

second problem today. I want to set up a debugger for qt on Mac OS 10.9. I followed this How-To. So I created the certificate but i stuck on the codesign process, but i haven't installed the gdb yet.

I followed the instructions in the readme but it didn't work.

```
cd gdb-VERSION
./configure
make
```

was ok, but

```
cp gdb/gdb /usr/local/bin/gdls
```

wasn’t.
Error:

```
cp gdb/gdb /Applications/gdb
cp: gdb/gdb: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance,
user3008155.

Comment: installed it successfully via macports and signed it as well. i can run it in terminal, but if i select it in QT Creator preferences as shown on the screenshot i still get the error "no debugger setup" when i press "Start debugging" in QT creator. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: forgot the screenshot :-D
http://abload.de/img/screenshot2013-11-20ajeski.png